# Call to Action Button Stuck in Middle of Page

Tags: html, css, button

My '**Click here to contact us!**' button is sticking to the middle of the page instead of floating at the bottom, here is the code and an image attached. I recently faced an issue where the button was changing size on being clicked which was rectified, however now my problem is it floating in the middle of the page.

Is this a problem with a margin or height set?

[image: Photo of the button floating in the middle right, whereas it is meant to be in the bottom left.]

[image: How the button is meant to be (bottom right)]

---

```css
* Call to Action */ 
.call-to-action {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Roboto, Sans Serif';
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 16px 31px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: auto;
}

.call-to-action a:hover {
  background-color: #C6DDF0;
  border: 1px solid #C6DDF0;
}

.call-to-action a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff
}

.call-to-action:hover {
  background-color: #C6DDF0;
}
```

```html
<!--Button Bottom Right-->
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?subject=Envirma Education | Media Production Unit 6&body=To the attention of sir/madam,
        
        Envirma Education | Media Production Unit 6" class="call-to-action">Click here to contact us! <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i>
        </a>
<!--End of Contact Call-To-Action-->
```

Comment: You are using `position:absolute` for the call to action button in your CSS. Using that is like saying this is absolutely where i want this button to appear.

Comment: It's very unclear which button is your call-to-action button: Get started or Click here to contact us. You should probably do something about that first, if you really want to have a call for action. ;) So which button is it?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't look anything like the screenshot, can you share link to the issue? It would be easier to help. The problem can be related to another element on the page.

Comment: I think you want `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`. Absolute positioned elements are positioned relative to it's nearest non-static parent, fixed positioned elements are positioned relative to the viewport.

Comment: @TVBZ was using the wrong technical term, sorry. The button I am referring to is the contact one displayed on the bottom right of my landing page. I fixed the initial issue by changing the position anchor.

Comment: @arieljuod Just done that, works. Thank you.